# How to process text but don't print it?

Tags: compiling

I have, for example, the following document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{vhistory}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{IncludeVersionHistory}
\setboolean{IncludeVersionHistory}{false}

\begin{document}

\vhCurrentVersion

\ifthenelse{\boolean{IncludeVersionHistory}}{
\begin{versionhistory}
    \vhEntry{0.1}{08.05.2015}{Author}{First draft}
\end{versionhistory}
}{}

\end{document}
```

If I set the variable `IncludeVersionHistory` to true, everything works as expected and `\vhCurrentVersion` prints 0.1. But now I don't want the version history to be included in the final pdf but still use the command to get the latest version. If I set `IncludeVersionHistory` to false the pdf just contains N/A (because the if clause doesn't get compiled).

A workaround would be to compile the document with the version history enabled so that the auxiliary data is generated and then compile it once again without the version history. I know it's not that much of an effort to do but I still want to know if there is a mechanism that doesn't need manual changes between compilations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Apparently, `\vhCurrentVersion` needs the environment `versionhistory` to be used (and two runs of compilation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can process in a box register so the aux data gets written, then only use the box depending on your flag:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{vhistory}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newbox\vhbox
\newboolean{IncludeVersionHistory}
\setboolean{IncludeVersionHistory}{true}

\begin{document}

\vhCurrentVersion

\setbox\vhbox\vbox{%
\begin{versionhistory}
    \vhEntry{0.1}{08.05.2015}{Author}{First draft}
\end{versionhistory}
\unskip\unpenalty\unpenalty}


\ifthenelse{\boolean{IncludeVersionHistory}}{
\unvbox\vhbox
}{

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. But if I set the variable to true the version history is not included in the pdf.

Comment: @happyMOOyear oops sorry, try now:-)

Comment: I think there is a problem with the `\begin{versionhistory} ... \end{versionhistory}` block. If I replace it with a simple sentence, the true/false switch works like a charm. But the actual version history never shows up.

Comment: @happyMOOyear sorry try now