# How to use bibentry with .bbl instead of .bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, xr

I have a 2 documents, and I want to make the references consistent. Let them be called document A and document B.

I compile document A as usual, which outputs a .bbl file. Now, I want to compile document B where (1) the citation numbers are identical to document A and (2) I want to remove the references list and print the bibliograph entries (not the citation number) in text.

For example, here is document A:

doca.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\nobibliography{my_bib1.bib, my_bib2.bib}

This is a reference to \cite{myref1} and \cite{myref2}. 

And, this is my in text bibliography entry:

\cite{myref1} \bibentry{myref1}

More text. More text.

\newpage
{
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
}

\end{document}
```

And, these are the .bib files I use in document A.

my_bib1.bib

```
@article{myref1,
  title={Paper Title 1},
  author={LastnameA, A and LastnameB, B and LastnameC, C},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:0000.00000},
  year={2024}
}
```

my_bib2.bib

```
@article{myref2,
  title={Paper Title 2},
  author={LastnameA, A and LastnameB, B and LastnameC, C},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:0000.00000},
  year={2024}
}
```

Now, in document B, I have the following (which clearly doesn't work):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}

\input{doca.bbl}

This is a reference to~\cite{myref1} and~\cite{myref2}. 

\cite{myref1} \bibentry{myref1}

More text.

\end{document}
```

I have 2 issues:

1. The first is `\bibentry` isn't work. To my understanding, I need to call `\nobibliography` before calling `\bibentry`; however, I don't call `\nobibliography` in document B because I am using the `.bbl` from document A. I believe this is why but don't know how to resolved.
2. The second is I cannot remove the references list from the document because the `.bbl` includes `\begin{thebibliography}` and `\end{thebibliography}`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? That is, printing the bibliography entries in text and also keeping the bibliography numbering consistent between the 2 documents? I can achieve one of these using the method above, but I can't get them both to work.

I understand I can use the `xr` or `xcite` packages for making references consistent, but I don't see a way they could be used to circumvent the issues mentioned above.

Comment: I have never really looked into `xcite`, but I half expect it should be able to help with issue 2. Without `xcite` you could still try and just do the `\input{doca.bbl}` in a box that you then don't typeset (I'm thinking of something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243874/35864).

Comment: The whole thing probably gets more complicated if you need to involve `\bibentry`, though.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the comment! This could work in part, but yes, I am still having trouble with `\bibentry` because I need to run `\nobibliography`.